# Delete ROOM method is not working (JAVA) How i fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-room, sql-delete

My delete method is not working. Here the DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface TodoDAO {
    @Insert
    public void insert(Todo todo);

    @Delete
    public void delete(Todo todo);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM todos")
    public LiveData<List<Todo>> getTodos();

    @Query("DELETE FROM todos WHERE id = :todoId")
    public void deleteFromId(int todoId);
}
```

Here the repository:

```
package com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.database;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TodoRepository {
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private Handler handler;
    private TodoDAO dao;

    public TodoRepository(Application application){
        TodoDatabase database = TodoDatabase.getInstance(application);
        this.dao = database.getTodoDao();

        this.executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        this.handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    public void addTodo(Todo todo){
        executorService.execute(() -> dao.insert(todo));
    }

    public void deleteTodo(Todo todo){
        executorService.execute(() -> dao.delete(todo));
    }

    public void deleteTodoFromId(int todoId){
        executorService.execute(() -> dao.deleteFromId(todoId));
    }

    public LiveData<List<Todo>> getTodos(){
        return dao.getTodos();
    }
}
```

Here the MainActivityViewModel

```
package com.bryanvalerio.todoapp;

import android.app.Application;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.database.Category;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.database.CategoryRepository;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.database.Todo;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.database.TodoRepository;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private LiveData<List<Todo>> allTodo;
    private LiveData<List<Category>> allCategory;
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public MainActivityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        this.categoryRepository = new CategoryRepository(application);
        this.todoRepository = new TodoRepository(application);

    }

    public void addTodo(Todo todo){
        todoRepository.addTodo(todo);
    }
    public void deleteTodo(Todo todo){
        todoRepository.deleteTodo(todo);
    }
    public LiveData<List<Todo>> getTodos(){
        allTodo = todoRepository.getTodos();
        return allTodo;
    }

    public void deleteTodoFromId(int todoId){
        todoRepository.deleteTodoFromId(todoId);
    }
}
```

Here the RecyclerView adapter (where i call the delete method)

```
package com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.MainActivity;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.MainActivityViewModel;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.R;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.TodoFragmentHandlers;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.TodosFragment;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.database.Todo;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.databinding.TodosItemLayoutBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TodoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Todo> todos;
    private TodoFragmentHandlers handlers;
    private MainActivityViewModel viewModel;

    public TodoAdapter(ArrayList<Todo> todos, MainActivityViewModel viewModel, TodoFragmentHandlers handlers) {
        this.todos = todos;
        this.handlers = handlers;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        TodosItemLayoutBinding todosItemLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.todos_item_layout,
                parent,
                false
        );
        return new ViewHolder(todosItemLayoutBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.todosItemLayoutBinding.setTodo(todos.get(position));

        holder.todosItemLayoutBinding.fabDelete.setOnClickListener(
                (view) -> {
                    boolean areYouSure = handlers.areYouSureDeleteTodo(view);

                    if(areYouSure){
                        viewModel.deleteTodoFromId(
                                todos.get(position).getId()
                        );
                    }

                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return todos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TodosItemLayoutBinding todosItemLayoutBinding;

        public ViewHolder(TodosItemLayoutBinding todosItemLayoutBinding) {
            super(todosItemLayoutBinding.getRoot());
            this.todosItemLayoutBinding = todosItemLayoutBinding;
        }
    }
}
```

Here the fragment code:

```
package com.bryanvalerio.todoapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.adapter.CategoryAdapter;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.adapter.TodoAdapter;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.database.Category;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.database.Todo;
import com.bryanvalerio.todoapp.databinding.FragmentTodosBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;


public class TodosFragment extends Fragment {
    private MainActivityViewModel viewModel;

    public TodosFragment(MainActivityViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentTodosBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_todos,
                container,
                false
        );


        TodoFragmentHandlers todoFragmentHandlers = new TodoFragmentHandlers(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), (MainActivity) getActivity());

        binding.setHandlers(todoFragmentHandlers);


        ArrayList<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<>();

        TodoAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoAdapter(todos, viewModel, todoFragmentHandlers);

        viewModel.getTodos().observe(
                getViewLifecycleOwner(), todos1 -> {
                    todos.clear();
                    for(Todo todo:todos1){
                        Log.v("TAG", todo.getTitle());
                        todos.add(todo);
                    }

                    Log.v("TAG", "__________________________________");

                    todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        binding.todosRecyclerView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);

        binding.todosRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new LinearLayoutManager(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext())
        );

        binding.categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new LinearLayoutManager(
                        getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                        false
                )
        );
        return binding.getRoot();
    }


}
```

EDIT: Here the areYouSUreToDeleteTodo() method that i use to display an AlertDialog (I don't know why i use atomic bolean):

````
public boolean areYouSureDeleteTodo(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        AtomicBoolean result = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        builder.setTitle("Confirm delete todo")
                .setMessage("Are you sure to delete a todo?");

        builder.setNegativeButton(
                "No",
                (dialogInterface, i) -> result.set(false)
        );

        builder.setPositiveButton(
                "Yes",
                (dialogInterface, i) -> result.set(true)
        );

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

        alertDialog.show();

        return result.get();
    }```

I tried the method `deleteFromId()` but it not worked.

 I ever do in this way and i don't know why not working, If you know how fix it plese tell me.

Thanks in advance
````

Comment: Did you debug whether the `deleteTodoFromId()` method gets called at all? The `areYouSure` variable might be blocking the method from ever being called, since we can't see what `areYouSureDeleteTodo()` returns (if it always returns false then your delete methods will not get called)

Comment: You right! I debugged the code and the problem is no the delete method. So, how i can fix it? I add the method in the body of question. Thank you!

Comment: I fix it! Thank you